# time subtract mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find the time difference between a mysql timestamp and the time now in php.

```
$timesince = strtotime("now") -  $row['DateTime'];
```

This is my attempt at doing it but it doesn't seem to work.

Also, really ideally I'd like the output to be in a nice format like: 34 minutes ago,2 hours 5 minutes ago 4,days 2 minutes ago etc.

Really, really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: +1 for a nice welcome to SO.  Also, if you're new here make sure to accept the answer you find to be the most suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtotime("now")` returns the time as seconds since the Unix epoch, i.e. an integer. A mysql "timestamp" field is going to be YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss. You first need to get those to be the same format. I'd recommend selecting the mysql timestamp field as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateTime)` so it returns an integer, and then you'll be able to do your math to get `$timesince` in seconds.

Then, like @Derek Adair said, check out the [PHP Date Object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Sorry my comments were meant to directed at you. I have used your approach but the numbers I get are vast ie 1290967451 when it should be in the 100s

Comment: @Sam Did you figure this out? What is the date in the MySQL column?

Comment: @Sam My preference for doing this is to actually get the difference in MySQL: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('DateTime')` and _then_ do the rest in PHP as `strtotime` is rather inefficient. Also-- `strtotime("now")` is equivalent to `time()` fyi.

Comment: Thanks v much, working fine now. I needed to change UNIX_TIMESTAMP('DateTime') to UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateTime). I glad it is faster in mysql, my only concern is that I'm not printing the entire array so am doing unecessary calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the manual for the [PHP Date Object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

simply using `date()` returns the current date.

Try something like...

```
$curDate = date();
$mysqlTimestamp = $row['timestamp'];

$dif = strtotime($curdate) - strtotime($mysqlTimestamp);
```